# unable to load json library while installing twitter api module

Tags: python, json, twitter

im trying to work with the twitter api with python3.3 in windows

while I try to install using

```
python setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
raise ImportError, "Unable to load a json library"
```

to solve this i install the simple json module manually

the error comes back again

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\schatterjee\workspace\test\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import twitter
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\twitter.py", line 50
    raise ImportError, "Unable to load a json library"
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

why is this persisting?

Comment: [Makes not much sense](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter/blob/master/twitter.py#L50) as Python 3 comes with a built-in json module. Does `import json` work when running the Python interpreter? (i.e. enter `python` to start the interpreter)

Comment: @poke import json works but import twitter gives that error. it's bizzare but it's occuring

Comment: Actually, exactly which Python library are you using, because that other one [has the same line](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/utils.py#L92)? Also are you sure your `python` command is a Python 3? Because neither looks Python 3 compatible.. Also, please post the full traceback.

Comment: im using twitter.py. probably they are not compatible but just the error is bizzare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the traceback *did help* a lot. The problem is not, as originally assumed, that there is no JSON library. Instead you get a syntax error on the line that *would* throw an error (it doesn’t throw it though!).

The reason you get the syntax error is because the displayed syntax is Python 2 syntax:

```
raise ExceptionType, "message"
```

This syntax is no longer a valid syntax in Python 3 but must be written as

```
raise ExceptionType(message)
```

The error supports my assumption that the Twitter library you picked is not compatible with Python 3. There are in fact multiple things within the library that would throw further syntax errors. I’m surprised that they didn’t add a check to the `setup.py` to inform you about this though.

So, unfortunately, you will not be able to use this library with Python 3, but need to use Python 2. You can install both Python 2 and Python 3 in parallel on your computer, if you want to.

You could however also look for a different library. Here are two that are compatible with Python 3; I haven’t tried either of them though:

- [Python Twitter Tools](http://mike.verdone.ca/twitter/)  ([GitHub](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter))
- [Wyvern](https://github.com/danxmoran/wyvern)

Comment: thanks so much. I realised the syntaxes have changed a bit. event print 'string' doesn't work now. would you recommend to report this bug to the API devs? +1 for the other twitter APIs. didn't know about them.

Comment: @codious Yes, I would ask for a Python 3 version. It’s the more-or-less official Python 3 library and there do not seem to be any (public) plans on a Python 3 version yet, so bringing this to attention definitely sounds like a good idea.